# Compare two dates not considering Year and giving incorrect answer

Tags: python

I have two dates I'm trying to compare in this format: `a = '10.2022'` (october 2022) and `b = '02.2023'` (February 2023)

When I enter a > b I expect to have False

Here is my code:

```
import datetime

a = '10-2022' # String date
b = '02-2023' # String date

date_format = '%m.%Y'

a = datetime.datetime.strptime(master_list[0][1], '%m-%Y').strftime(date_format)

b = datetime.datetime.strptime(master_list[0][2], '%m-%Y').strftime(date_format)
```

So I have `a = '10.2022 '` and `b = '02.2023'`.

`a > b` returns True which is not correct because Oct 2022 is obviously before Feb 2023. Not sure what's not working

Comment: @sj95126 please try to fix _all problems_ when you edit.

Comment: When you execute your comparison, you are comparing them *after* they have been converted to strings, so you are just doing string comparison and `a` is alphabetically after `b`...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: I added the python tag to get more eyes on the question. I made no attempt to fix any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

date_format = '%m.%Y'

a = datetime.datetime.strptime('10-2022', '%m-%Y') 
b = datetime.datetime.strptime('02-2023', '%m-%Y') 

print(type(a))
print(a)
print(f'a is greater than b when both are datetime: {a>b}')
print()

# now convert back to format you want...
a_as_str = a.strftime(date_format)
b_as_str = b.strftime(date_format)

print(type(a_as_str))
print(a_as_str)
print(f'a is greater than b when both are strings: {a_as_str>b_as_str}')
```

##### Output:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2022-10-01 00:00:00
a is greater than b when both are datetime: False

<class 'str'>
10.2022
a is greater than b when both are strings: True
```